# Flink 1.5-SNAPSHOT is built when I try to build 1.4 from source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm following the [documentation to build Flink 1.4](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/start/building.html#build-flink) but instead Flink `1.5-SNAPSHOT` is built.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flink-streaming-java 1.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (dependency-convergence) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- directory-maven-plugin:0.1:highest-basedir (directories) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] Highest basedir set to: /Users/amar/Downloads/flink-master
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ flink-streaming-java_2.11 ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not correct. It shows how to build the current master branch which is always the latest SNAPSHOT version (currently `1.5-SNAPSHOT`). Before a new minor Flink version is released, we fork off a release branch. For Flink 1.4 this branch is called `release-1.4`.

You can build Flink 1.4-SNAPSHOT (the latest version in the dev branch with all bugfixes for Flink 1.4) by checking out the `release-1.4` branch before calling Maven. So the commands should be:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink
cd flink
git checkout release-1.4
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```

If you want to build a specific version, i.e., not the latest SNAPSHOT of a release, you can checkout a tag. For Flink 1.4.0 this would be `git checkout release 1.4.0` instead of `git checkout release 1.4`.